Why is there an $ε_0$ term in electric polarisation and electric field relationship?
$$\mathbf{P}=\chi\epsilon_0\mathbf{E}.$$
Why is there an $ε_0$ term in this equation? What are the theoretical reasons for that?

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vacuum_permittivity

@JonCuster I know that it represents vacuum permittivity. But why does vacuum permittivity appear here?

It's just a definition. Polarization measures the difference between the dielectric field in a medium and the polarization field that would be in vacuum, $\varepsilon_0 \mathbf{e}$,
$$\mathbf{d} = \varepsilon_0 \mathbf{e} + \mathbf{p} \ .$$
Now, for isotropic media, all these 3 fields are aligned, and you're free to define a non-dimensional coefficient $\chi$ of the medium, the electric susceptibility, from the relation $\mathbf{p} = \chi \varepsilon_0 \,\mathbf{e}$.
If this holds, you can write
$$\mathbf{d} = (\varepsilon_0 + \chi \varepsilon_0 ) \mathbf{e} = (1 + \chi) \varepsilon_0 \mathbf{e} = \varepsilon_r \varepsilon_0 \mathbf{e} \ .$$
You could do different choices, but one reason for the $\varepsilon_0$ to be there is to define a non-dimensional electric susceptibility, and a non-dimensional relative permittivity $\varepsilon_r$.
If you define the relation between polarization and the electric field as $\mathbf{p} = \widetilde{\chi} \mathbf{e}$, that "modified elextric susceptibility" would be dimensional and equal to $\widetilde{\chi} = \chi \varepsilon_0$, since the behavior of the medium doesn't depend on your definitions, or other choices like the choice of dimensional units.

Thanks a lot for the answer

You're welcome. For the usual anonymous downvoter, LOL as usual

The answer is really down to history.
A tolerable unit system ought to have $\vec E,\vec D,\vec P$ have the same units, and $\vec B,\vec H,\vec M$ have the same units. A good unit system should enforce that all 6 of these quantities have the same units.
A rationalised unit system eliminates the appearance of $4\pi$ in its rendition of Maxwell's equations.
Before there was SI units, there was a horrendous headache between ESU and EMU units. Both of these were not rationalised, and they are not good either. And because they were the first ones to come up with a full unit system, they did not realise that people needed to have names for units to help keep track of things. Worse, their units of the electromagnetic stuff had all combinations of square roots of lengths, square roots of masses and square roots of time. It was so confusing that it quickly got abandoned. The abandonment had nothing to do with confusion, though; people actually can work with bad units, but they really hated when units are inconvenient---both ESU and EMU are convenient in one half of things, and were a factor or two of the speed of light, huge or tiny, in the other half. That was what caused their abandonment. (Nobody actually used ESU; the committee that formalised the then-existing unit system and called it EMU, noted that ESU is also a possibility. Then people had something to compare, and noted this half-half behaviour.)
Between the two of them, a chimera was born. It is now known as the Gaussian unit system, named after that famous mathematician, Gauß, that is impossible to avoid in a modern education system. The Gaußian unit system combines the convenient parts of both ESU and EMU, and accidentally became a good unit system; i.e. all 6 quantities have the same units. However, it is not rationalised, and so instead of $\varepsilon_0$, it has the appearance of $4\pi$ randomly in it. And so then you would ask not why $\varepsilon_0$, but would instead ask why $4\pi$ appears right there. i.e. $\vec p=4\pi\chi\vec E$ as opposed to $\vec p=\varepsilon_0\chi\vec E$, both equally deserving of question.
After the confusion of the above three unit systems, people decided that enough confusion was had by all, and so SI was born. SI is rationalised, and so you don't have $4\pi$ in Maxwell's equations, but instead have it in Coulomb's force law. However, it was slightly before people found out how to get both rationalised and goodness. As such, it introduced both $\varepsilon_0$ and $\mu_0$, satisfying $\varepsilon_0\mu_0c^2=1$, and sprinkled them all over the place. It is thus rationalised but not good, but had a nice behaviour of not having confusions in charge, current, and all the units for the fields. No more square root units.
Sadly, we have not decided to use Heaviside-Lorentz units. Because if we had, then there is neither of the nuisance of $\varepsilon_0$ and $\mu_0$, nor the nuisances of the $4\pi$, and so we would all be using units that are both rationalised and good.
